# No Run Tab and no logs in Run Tab in Android Studio Flamingo

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.0, android-studio-3.2

Why there is no logs in Run Tab and even when I run the app, the Run Tab doesn't show automatically in Android Studio Flamingo.

This started happening after I **upgraded** to AS Flamingo.

Tried to open Run Tab from `Views` -> `Tools Windows` -> Run but still it shows only this

> 04/27 11:56:26: Launching 'app' on Xiaomi Redmi Note 8 Pro.
> Install successfully finished in 7 s 686 ms.
> $ adb shell am start -n ---- -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
> Open logcat panel for Xiaomi Redmi Note 8 Pro

Comment: I just updated my Android Studio Earl to Flamingo and there is no logs in Run Tab!

Comment: Let's just wait... https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37137285

Answer (score 0):

Dominik has provided a link to the google issue tracker. You can find more detailed answer there: issuetracker.google.com/issues/37137285

Here is the gist of it:

After upgrading from Android Studio Eel to the Flamingo version, all logs stopped logging to console. They are only available in the logcat window. Run window console displays a link "Open logcat panel for {device}".

After revamping logcat capabilities, colors, filtering etc, it was preferred to have single source of truth and not spend additional time on adding all this new functionality to console.

You can change configuration from Run/Edit configurations switch to Miscellaneous tab and under "Logcat" select "Show Logcat automatically". This will display Logcat window instead of Run window when you start the application.

Answer (score -1):

Android Studio new update removes Logs from Run Section.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You are just stating the fact in a line. That's not the answer though. -1